# ImageSpan adds space above image in some API level

Tags: android, fromhtml

I convert HTML string to spannable by using `HtmlCompat.fromHtml(...)`, the `ImageGetter` I use simply uses Glide to download images. By using `ContextCompat.getDrawable(...)` for comparison it gives similar result indeed.

In emulator with API level 16, it displays correctly like this:

[image: ImageSpan in API 16]

However in emulator with API level 28 it gives extra space above the image like this:

[image: ImageSpan in API 28]

Would anyone help me solving this inconsistency problem? Thank you.

---

#### Code snippet

```
val spanned = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(html, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY, Html.ImageGetter {
    ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableResId)?.apply {
        setBounds(0, 0, intrinsicWidth, intrinsicHeight)
    }
}, tagHandler)
```